# Bash sqlite3 -line | How to convert to JSON format

Tags: json, bash, awk, sqlite, grep

I want to convert my sqlite data from my database to JSON format.

I would like to use this syntax:

sqlite3 -line members.db "SELECT * FROM members LIMIT 3" > members.txt

OUTPUT:

```
      id = 1
   fname = Leif
   gname = Håkansson
genderid = 1

      id = 2
   fname = Yvonne
   gname = Bergman
genderid = 2

      id = 3
   fname = Roger
   gname = Sjöberg
genderid = 1
```

How to do this with nice and structur code in a for loop?
(Only in Bash)

I have tried some awk and grep but not with a great succes yet.

Would be nice with some tips.

I want a result similar to this:

```js
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "fname":"Leif",
    "gname":"Hakansson",
    "genderid":1
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "fname":"Yvonne",
    "gname":"Bergman",
    "genderid":2
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "fname":"Roger",
    "gname":"Sjberg",
    "genderid":1
  }
}
```

Comment: This may help... http://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/01/18/to-json-or-not-to-json/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I would prefer to parse sqlite output with a single line per record rather than the very wordy output format you suggested with `sqlite3 -line`. So, I would go with this:

```
sqlite3 members.db "SELECT * FROM members LIMIT 3"
```

which gives me this to parse:

```
1|Leif|Hakansson|1
2|Yvonne|Bergman|2
3|Roger|Sjoberg|1
```

I can now parse that with `awk` if I set the input separator to `|` with

```
awk -F '|'
```

and pick up the 4 fields on each line with the following and save them in an array like this:

```
{ id[++i]=$1; fname[i]=$2; gname[i]=$3; genderid[i]=$4 }
```

Then all I need to do is print the output format you need at the end. However, you have double quotes in your output and they are a pain to quote in `awk`, so I temporarily use another pipe symbol (`|`) as a double quote and then, at the very end, I get `tr` to replace all the pipe symbols with double quotes - just to make the code easier on the eye. So the total solution looks like this:

```
sqlite3 members.db "SELECT * FROM members LIMIT 3" | awk -F'|' '
   # sqlite output line - pick up fields and store in arrays
   { id[++i]=$1; fname[i]=$2; gname[i]=$3; genderid[i]=$4 }

   END {
      printf "[\n";
      for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
         printf "  {\n"
         printf "    |id|:%d,\n",id[j]
         printf "    |fname|:|%s|,\n",fname[j]
         printf "    |gname|:|%s|,\n",gname[j]
         printf "    |genderid|:%d\n",genderid[j]
         closing="  },\n"
         if(j==i){closing="  }\n"}
         printf closing;
      }
      printf "]\n";
   }' | tr '|' '"'
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help !

Comment: Pleasure. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 16):

If your sqlite3 is compiled with the json1 extension (or if you can obtain a version of sqlite3 with the json1 extension), then you can use it to generate JSON objects (one JSON object per row).  For example:

```
select json_object('id', id, 'fname', fname, 'gname', gname, 'genderid', genderid) ...
```

You can then use a tool such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to convert the stream of objects into an array of objects, e.g. pipe the output of the sqlite3 to `jq -s .`.

(A less tiresome alternative might be to use the sqlite3 function json_array(), which produces an array, which you can reassemble into an object using jq.)

If the json1 extension is unavailable, then you could use the following as a starting point:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "["; } 
 function out() {if (n++) {print ","}; if (line) {print "{" line "}"}; line="";}
 function trim(x) { sub(/^ */, "", x); sub(/ *$/, "", x); return x; }
 NF==0 { out(); next}; 
 {if (line) {line = line ", " }
  i=index($0,"="); 
  line = line "\"" trim(substr($0,1,i-1)) ": \"" substr($0, i+2) "\""}
 END {out(); print "]"} '
```

Alternatively, you could use the following jq script, which converts numeric strings that occur on the RHS of "=" to numbers:

```
  def trim: sub("^ *"; "") | sub(" *$"; "");
  def keyvalue: index("=") as $i 
    | {(.[0:$i] | trim): (.[$i+2:] | (tonumber? // .))};
  [foreach (inputs, "") as $line ({object: false, seed: {} };
     if ($line|trim) == "" then { object: .seed, seed : {} }
     else {object: false, 
           seed: (.seed + ($line | keyvalue)) }
     end;
     .object | if . and (. != {}) then . else empty end ) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 10):

Just type `-json` argument with SQLite 3.33.0 or higher and get json output:

```
$ sqlite3 -json database.db "select * from TABLE_NAME"
```

from SQLite Release 3.33.0 note:

> ...
>
> 6. CLI enhancements:
>
> - Added four new output modes: "box", "json", "markdown", and "table".
> - The "column" output mode automatically expands columns to contain the longest output row and automatically turns ".header" on if it has
>   not been previously set.
> - The "quote" output mode honors ".separator"
> - The decimal extension and the ieee754 extension are built-in to the CLI
>
> ...

Comment: Pro tip: 

To see the the output as pretty formatted JSON, run:

```sqlite3 -json database.db "select * from TABLE_NAME" | jq .```

This requires that you have `jq` installed on your machine

Answer (score 1):

[Sqlite-utils](https://sqlite-utils.datasette.io/en/stable/cli.html) does exactly what you're looking for. By default, the output will be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never to plug jo.

Save sqlite3 to a text file.

Get [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) (jo's also available in distro repos)

and use this bash script.

```
while read line
do 
    id=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f1`
    fname=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f2`
    gname=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f3`
    genderid=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f4`
    jsonline=`jo id="$id" fname="$fname" gname="$gname" genderid="$genderid"`
    json="$json $jsonline"
done < "$1"

jo -a $json
```

Answer (score -1):

Please don't create (or parse) json with `awk`. There are dedicated tools for this. Tools like [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).
While first and foremost a html, xml and json parser, `xidel` can also parse plain text.

I'd like to offer a very elegant solution using this tool (with much less code than `jq`).
I'll assume your *'members.txt'*.

First to create a sequence of each json object to-be:

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery 'tokenize($raw,"\n\n")'
```

Or...

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery 'tokenize($raw,"\n\n") ! (position(),.)'
1
      id = 1
   fname = Leif
   gname = Håkansson
genderid = 1
2
      id = 2
   fname = Yvonne
   gname = Bergman
genderid = 2
3
      id = 3
   fname = Roger
   gname = Sjöberg
genderid = 1
```

...to better show you the individual items in the sequence.

Now you have 3 multi-line strings. To turn each item/string into another sequence where each item is a new line:

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery 'tokenize($raw,"\n\n") ! x:lines(.)'
```

*(`x:lines(.)` is a shorthand for `tokenize(.,'\r\n?|\n')`)*

Now for each line tokenize on the " = " (which creates yet another sequence) and save it to a variable. For the first line for example this sequence is `("id","1")`, for the second line `("fname","Leif")`, etc.:

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery 'tokenize($raw,"\n\n") ! (for $x in x:lines(.) let $a:=tokenize($x," = ") return ($a[1],$a[2]))'
```

Finally remove leading whitespace (`normalize-space()`), create a json object (`{| {key-value-pair} |}`) and put all json objects in an array (`[ ... ]`):

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery '[tokenize($raw,"\n\n") ! {|for $x in x:lines(.) let $a:=tokenize($x," = ") return {normalize-space($a[1]):$a[2]}|}]'
```

Prettified + output:

```
xidel -s members.txt --xquery '
  [
    tokenize($raw,"\n\n") ! {|
      for $x in x:lines(.)
      let $a:=tokenize($x," = ")
      return {
        normalize-space($a[1]):$a[2]
      }
    |}
  ]
'
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "fname": "Leif",
    "gname": "Håkansson",
    "genderid": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "fname": "Yvonne",
    "gname": "Bergman",
    "genderid": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "fname": "Roger",
    "gname": "Sjöberg",
    "genderid": "1"
  }
]
```

**Note**: For `xidel-0.9.9.7173` and newer `--json-mode=deprecated` is needed to create a json array with `[` `]`. The new (XQuery 3.1) way to create a json array is to use `array{` `}`.