# How to design SQL model to store multi-level data?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am trying to store and a multi-level data on SQL database. I want to know what are the various ways to store multi-level data on the SQL database and retrieve it in JSON format. For the better understanding I will display the data in JSON format.

For example, I have a group of different categories having id, category (Employed, Student, Self-Employed) and at least three users:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'category': 'Employed',
    'users': [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Similarly, Each user has following attributes:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Jason Doe',
    'email': 'jason@doe.com',
    'status': {...}
}
```

Every User has status (open, active, closed) which is made up of the following attributes:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'status': 'open'
}
```

So, I am confused whether I should create separate tables for group, user and status or put everything in one table and retrieve it as a JSON object. I am using Flask SQLAlchemy for this project.

Comment: If your data is in JSON format, why not look into a NoSQL solution? Unless you have specific constraints surrounding your DB choice, [tinydb](https://pypi.org/project/tinydb/) is a simple solution for your data.

Comment: @vtasca That would be excellent choice, but data is not in JSON format I have to store data in relational format and want to retrieve data in JSON format and as part of my solution I have to use Relational database.

Comment: You can look at [SQLite utils](https://sqlite-utils.datasette.io/en/stable/cli.html#returning-json) . I found this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048347/bash-sqlite3-line-how-to-convert-to-json-format)